# PHP switch/case statement with case-insensitive string comparison

Tags: php

Switch/case string comparison is case-sensitive.

```
<?php
$smart = "crikey";

switch ($smart) {
     case "Crikey":
         echo "Crikey";
         break;
     case "Hund":
         echo "Hund";
         break;
     case "Kat":
         echo "Kat";
         break;
     default:
         echo "Alt Andet";
}
?>
```

Above code prints "Alt Andet", but I would like to compare strings case-insensitively and print "Crikey". How can I do that?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why do you think a switch statement would be case insensitive? `crikey` and `Crikey` aren't the same. Knowing that, work around it and `strtoupper` or `strtolower` the values. Alternatively, uppercase the 1st letter of your variable when doing comparisons. Also, why would you want it that way anyway?

Comment: He just told you--Force everything to lower case with strtolower($smart),  make your case "crickey": and so on and so forth.

Comment: Just use a lowercased string to switch and update your cases: https://eval.in/307176

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Convert the input to either uppercase or lowercase, problem solved.

```
<?php
$smart = "cRikEy";

switch (strtolower($smart)) {
     case "crikey": // Note the lowercase chars
         echo "Crikey";
         break;
     case "hund":
         echo "Hund";
         break;
     case "kat":
         echo "Kat";
         break;
     default:
         echo "Alt Andet";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [`stristr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) function on case statements. `stristr()` is **case-insensitive** [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) and *returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end.*

```
<?php

$smart = "crikey";

switch ($smart) {
     case stristr($smart, "Crikey"):
         echo "Crikey";
         break;
     case stristr($smart, "Hund"):
         echo "Hund";
         break;
     case stristr($smart, "Kat"):
         echo "Kat";
         break;
     default:
         echo "Alt Andet";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use lower case inputs then you can convert them to capitalized first character of each word in a string

> ucwords — Uppercase the first character of each word in a string

```
<?php
$smart = "crikey";

switch (ucwords($smart)) {
     case "Crikey":
         echo "Crikey";
         break;
     case "Hund":
         echo "Hund";
         break;
     case "Kat":
         echo "Kat";
         break;
     default:
         echo "Alt Andet";
}
?>
```

**helpful links from doc:**

[first character of each word](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php)
[Make a string's first character uppercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)
[Make a string lowercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
[Make a string uppercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)